# In J2ME, Does RMS(Record Management System) store records permanently?

Tags: java, java-me, rms

I am working on J2ME mobile application using Netbeans IDE 6.9 vesion. My application is working fine means inserts the records into the RMS and I can list the records in the system's default phone.

My problem is, Whenever I run the application it flushes the records and storing again freshly. It means that records are storing temporarily. I want to store records permanently and I've read different answers in Stack Overflow but not clear. Please provide me solution to this problem.

Comment: Please help me out in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Records in RMS are stored permanently - until you uninstall your app. If the records disappears when you close/re-open your app, then something in your code is doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that data in RMS are not persistent between sessions in WTK emulator, then check this: [Data in J2ME RecordStore does not persist across sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1704509/1028256) - it says that NetBeans uninstalls midlet on each launch, so it clears RMS of course. In this case you can just start emulator from WTK launcher instead (just build jad/jar files in NetBEans and launch jad in WTK emulator).

If you experience this issue on real device, then check that you close RMS properly. If you don't close it, changes may be lost on some devices. See my reply here: [J2ME RMS - Best practice for opening/closing record store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29129946/1028256)